# How to retrieve data from SQLite faster in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following info in my database (example):

```
longitude (real): 70.74
userid (int): 12
```

This is how i fetch it:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect(dbpath)
    with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT latitude, userid FROM message')
    con.commit()
    print "executed"
    while True:
        tmp = cur.fetchone()
        if tmp != None:
            info.append([tmp[0],tmp[1]])
        else:
            break
```

To get the same info on the form [70.74, 12]
What else can I do to speed up this process? At 10,000,000 rows this takes approx 50 seconds, as I'm  aiming for 200,000,000 rows - I never get through this, possible to a memory leak or something like that?

Comment: If `userid` is already an `int`, why create a new `int`?

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect, I actually saved userid as text to conserve any leading zeros.

Comment: What is your measure? How fast does this run and what type of improvement are you hoping for??

Answer (score 1):

From the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) documentation:

> A Row instance serves as a highly optimized row_factory for Connection objects. It tries to mimic a tuple in most of its features.

Since a `Row` closely mimics a tuple, depending on your needs you may not even need to unpack the results.

However, since your numerical types are stored as strings, we do need to do some processing. As @Jon Clements pointed out, the cursor is an iterable, so we can just use a comprehension, obtaining the `float` and `int`s at the same time.

```py
import sqlite3 as lite

with lite.connect(dbpath) as conn:
  cur = conn.execute('SELECT latitude, userid FROM message')

  items = [[float(x[0]), int(x[1])] for x in cur]
```

**EDIT:** We're not making any changes, so we don't need to call `commit`.

Comment: You can drop the `.fetchall` as that will pull a list of tuples by default... it'll act as an iterable otherwise, so `for x in cur` is fine. One could even drop the creation of the cursor object and execute on the connection object...

Comment: Thanks! I'll add those suggestions now.